# Change form class to file upload in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, class

I am working on a file upload script.  There are several directories to where the files need to be uploaded, however, I am trying to use a single form to do this.

With that said, I am able to change the form class using jQuery in an attempt to use a single form.

Here is the form:

```
 <form method="post" class="addFileClass" id="addFileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" class="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
   <button type="button" id="newfilesubmit">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

These links are what I am using to begin the form class change:

```
 <a href="#" class="addDentalFile">Add Dental File</a>
 <a href="#" class="addLifeADDFile">Add Life ADD File</a>
 .....several more.....
```

Using these hrefs, I can use jQuery to change the form class:

```
 $('.addDentalFile').on('click', function(e)
 {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#addFileForm').trigger('reset');
   $('#addFileForm').removeClass();
   $('#addFileForm').addClass('dentalFileForm');
   $('.addFileModal').modal('show');
 });
 ......same format for the other links......
```

Using the above, I can successfully alter the class for the form ID #addFileForm.

This is where I am stuck.  Here is my current upload script:

```
 $('#newfilesubmit').on('click', function()
 {
   var formData = new FormData($('#addFileForm')[0]); // <-class should be passed here, but how when the class will be different?
   $.ajax({
     url: 'api/uploadFile.php',
     data: formData,
     async: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     cache: false,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(data)
     {
       // doing success stuff
     },
     fail: function()
     {
       // doing fail stuff
     }
   });
 });
```

The above script works when the ID remains the same.  But since now I am using the class of the form, the jQuery needs to be able to identify the new class (I hope I'm saying that right).

With all this said, how can I change the variable formData whenever a new class is passed?  Is this possible?

Comment: if the form itself is not changing then what is? it seems like you want to change the ajax url based on the class name, not the form itself. if this inference is not correct please update the question and make it more clear.

Comment: You are using same form to submit on both type of links and you also have one ajax submit operation. What benefit do you want to take by changing class of form ? Could you explain ?

Comment: @gschambial - in all honesty, I am merely trying to find the best way to utilize a single form when different files are being submitted.  If changing the form class is a bad idea, then perhaps I shouldn't go that route.

Comment: @JohnBeasley that's not a bad idea. But, what you should do is that you should check the class currently applied on the form element and then use a variable to store the url of the request, depending on the class. Then, finally use that variable in the `url` property of `ajax` request. I hope, it will help.

Comment: @JohnBeasley you can use `var currentUrl = $('form').attr('class')` to get the class currently applied on the `form` and then use `url : currentUrl` in ajax request.

Comment: @gschambial - I was definitely going to use the url as a variable.  I was just trying to save on writing so much code.  I know I could "simply" write like 12 different upload scripts with 12 different forms to upload 12 different files.  That would end up being over 5000 lines of code - (5000 is exaggerating, but you get my point)

Comment: @JohnBeasley I have posted an answer with code of approach i am talking about. I don't think so, it could ever lead to extra 5KLOC. Try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. On click of submit button, Just get URL based on the current applied class on form.

```
$('#newfilesubmit').on('click', function()
     {
       var formData = new FormData($('#addFileForm')[0]); // <-
       var currentclass = $('form').attr('class');
       var currentUrl;
       if(currenClass == 'dentalClass'){
         currentUrl = 'api/upload.php';
       }else if(currenClass == 'dentalClass'){
         currentUrl = 'api/someotherfile.php';
       }
    //class should be passed here, but how when the class will be different?
       $.ajax({
         url: currentUrl,
         data: formData,
         async: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         cache: false,
         type: 'POST',
         success: function(data)
         {
           // doing success stuff
         },
         fail: function()
         {
           // doing fail stuff
         }
       });
     });
```

Comment: I had to tweek the IF statement you provided....supposed to be double equals ==, not single equal =.  This had me going crazy for like an hour.  But in the end, this is exactly what worked for me.  Now I can pass the class and get the appropriate URL script to upload the necessary file.  Thank you so much, gschambial.  I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you want to change some behavior based upon `#addFileForm`'s class. To do so you can just check the class by doing:

```
switch($('#addFileForm').attr('class')){
case 'dentalFileForm':
 //do stuff
 break;
//etc. 
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for.  I will attempt and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using classes like `dentalFileForm` you could make them something like `file-dental` and then change your JS selector like so:

```
var formData = new FormData($('form[class^="file-"]')[0]);
```